# Symfony2, call part of a form in an Ajax query

Tags: symfony

I have a form in Symfony.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('volume', IntegerType::class, array())
    ;

    $builder->add('product', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'data' => '1',
        'mapped' => false,
        'choices' => array(
                '1' => 'One',
                '2' => 'Two',
            ),
        )
    );

    $builder->add('deliveryType', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'expanded' => true,
        'data' => 1,
        'choices' => array(
            Command::STANDARD_DELIVERY => 'Standard',
            Command::EXPRESS_DELIVERY => 'Express',
        ),
    ));
}
```

But the field `deliveryType` is loaded in another template called with an ajax request.
But of corse I have this error:
`Variable "form" does not exist in ... at line 26`

How can I put a part of a form in another template?

Here is my main template:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  {{ form_start(form)}}
  {{ form_errors(form) }}

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
          {{ form_row(form.product) }}
          {{ form_row(form.volume, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
          {{ form_row(form.town) }}
      </div>
  </div>

  <div id="content-delivery-range"><!-- Block loaded by ajax --></div>

  <br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Continuer </button>

  {{ form_end(form) }}

</div>
```

And now my template called with an Ajax request:

```
{{ deliveryRange|first|date('d M') }}
{{ deliveryRange|last|date('d M') }}

{% for d in deliveryRange %}
  {{ d|date('l') }} <br>
  <small>{{ d|intl_date('d') }} {{ d|date('M') }}</small>
{% endfor %}

{{ form_row(form.deliveryType) }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

I have used an **event listener** with `PRE_SUBMIT`:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('volume', IntegerType::class, array())
    ;

    $builder->add('product', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'data' => '1',
        'mapped' => false,
        'choices' => array(
                '1' => 'One',
                '2' => 'Two',
            ),
        )
    );

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSubmit'));

}

public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();

    $form->add('deliveryType', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'expanded' => true,
        'data' => Command::STANDARD_DELIVERY,
        'choices' => array(
            Command::STANDARD_DELIVERY => 'Standard',
            Command::EXPRESS_DELIVERY => 'Express',
        ),
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to include the "deliveryType" form element as part of the initial form render.

Then, your ajax call could just return the necessary values which you insert using jquery/javascript/etc.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have the choice. Because this form is going to be loaded each time there is a modification in the main form.